# lines+=line / TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python, sqlite, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to communicate with the arduino and get the data saved in the microSD, where it has user and password, and then move to the sqlite database, however I stopped in that part where it returns me that error.

I think it's something related to encode, so I researched, but I do not know how to do it.

```
lines=""

    with serial.Serial('COM5',9600,timeout=2) as ser:
        line = ser.readline()
        lines+=line
        print (lines)
```

If anyone knows how to fix this error and can already advance how I make it to my database, I will be grateful.

Comment: Try `lines = b''`.

Comment: Right, solved. Would you know how I could link microSD data to my GUI database?

Comment: That's a different question, I think.

Comment: yes, but would you know how to do it? Can we speak by email?

Comment: @felipi you should ask your new question, this would help you a lot and anyone having similar issue.

Comment: @M.R.The problem is that I already did, and they said that it was vague, but there is more what I say being that I asked for help in getting the data of the arduino in a microSD and to pass to my GUI linked to the sqlite database, that? Has no way.